# how to find the file that generates a url into the ftp?

Tags: url, joomla, ftp-client

I built a site with joomla , demo.intermediabusiness.it , once finished the site , I found there the url that were resolved in an absurd way , these url here
my problem now is figuring out which file derive this url to remove it , but I can not in any way find out which files can be linked !

demo.intermediabusiness.it/jfL2a/5TyQ-Kashukashu-bag-Sale-TWPm.html

demo.intermediabusiness.it/jfL2a/3d_Tent-tarp-how-to-stretch-sI5-N.html

demo.intermediabusiness.it/jfL2a/5o_Louis-Vuitton-fold-sY6-R.html

demo.intermediabusiness.it/jfL2a/1p_Apparel-clerk-pF0-I.html

demo.intermediabusiness.it/jfL2a/5r_Classical-guitar-music-nS5-L.html

Answer (score 0):

File is **router.php** its located in the folder of component that serves the content. If you want to change URLs I suggest you install a 3rd party component to help you with that. Like sh404sef you will have a lot of URL control in an easy way.